# How can I rotate my signature in Preview?

Tags: macos, preview

I have scanned my signature and can insert it just fine, but at the wrong angle!

How can I rotate it (90 deg)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've been having the same problem, but I solved it by opening the pdf file in Preview, hitting `File > Duplicate`, then adding the signature in the newly created file. This corrects the orientation of the file so that Preview can identify lines and you can just click on them with the signature tool (from the Annotate/Edit toolbar) and add your signature.

Answer (score 11):

You can also rotate signatures and other annotations, like text boxes or rectangles, by arbitrary angles:

Hold the <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> key and do a rotation gesture with two fingers on a trackpad.

As far as I know this only works with trackpads and is undocumented. It works on macOS High Sierra.

This is from a related question on AskDifferent: [How do you rotate inserts in Apple Mac OS preview 7?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/263964/122152)

Comment: Why is this not the accepted answer! Works like a charm

Comment: I can confirm that on Big Sur rotating a signature with fingers on the trackpad works even without `Command ⌘` being pressed. Just select the signature first. But correcting page orientation fixes the cause instead, so that you should not need to rotate the singantue at all.

Answer (score 5):

This thread addresses the problem best:

https://discussions.apple.com/message/16821750#16821750

Basically the issue is with Acrobat formatting scanned PDFs in a way that makes Preview think it is rotated.

The answer above about exporting to a new PDF and then trying to insert a scanned signature in the new PDF via Preview's annotation tools works to fix the problem.

Comment: The link is dead now.

Answer (score 3):

To rotate the whole image:

- Open the image file in Preview
- Click "Tools" in the menubar
- Click "Rotate Left" or "Rotate Right"

To rotate only part of the image

- Open the image file in Preview
- Select the signature part
- Hit Command-x to cut or Command-c to copy
- Hit Command-n to make a new file from the cut or copied part
- Click "Tools" in the menubar
- Click "Rotate Left" or "Rotate Right"
- Hit Command-a to select all
- Hit Command-c to Copy
- In the first document, hit command-v to paste the rotated part
- Copy and paste small background-colored areas to fill in where the original signature was

Comment: Thanks, David - but that rotates the PDF File - not the signature :(

Comment: Have fixed. Try now.

Comment: Hi David. Thanks for wanting to help but still not working. Are you aware that Preview has a built-in signature annotation tool? (Open preview, open a PDF file, choose Tools -> Annotate -> Signature)  I think you're referring to rotation normal images in preview, not signatures (which cannot be copied by commanda-x or command-c). The signatures are added by going to Preferences (still in Preview) -> Signatures.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem and found that I could work around it with `File > Export…`. After closing the original and opening the exported version, the signature orientation was correct.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up scanning a new signature in sideways via the camera. So now I have a rotated signature and a normal one should the issue come up again.

Hopefully Apple fixes this at some point.

Answer (score 0):

I did not export it but I copied the signature on a blank Pages document.  I found that after I closed it, and reopened it, the orientation was correct.