# How do you rotate inserts in Apple Mac OS preview 7?

Tags: mac, preview

It happens that I noticed a text insert I had  pasted in an  image in Preview 7 (Sierra on MacBookAir had been rotated
I don't know how this happened but the text insert is definitely not horizontal.
So there must be a way to rotate inserts. I haven't yet found out.
Can anyone tell me?

Comment: I found out here :  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5222408?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 11):

You can rotate inserts and annotations, like text boxes, rectangles or signatures, by arbitrary angles:

Hold the <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> key and rotate the selected annotation with two fingers on a trackpad.

As far as I know this only works with trackpads and is undocumented. It works on macOS High Sierra.

This is from an apple communities question: [How can I rotate the text box in Preview](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5222408?start=0&tstart=0)

Comment: Still supported in 2023 with Sonoma `14.2.1` 

Comment: This stops working in Sonoma 14.3. Attempts to rotate an annotation skews the annotation instead of rotating it.

Answer (score 3):

Rotating with command + the trackpad (per the other answer) worked for me, but only after I enabled the "rotate" gesture in `System Preferences > Trackpad` (see screenshot) (OS X 10.14 Mojave)

[image]